# Linear Transformation using Standard Matrix

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $$A= 
          \begin{bmatrix}
          -8 & 3 & 6\\
          -3 & 1 & 2 \\
          -3 & 1 & 3\\
          \end{bmatrix}
$$ be the standard matrix representing the linear transformation $$L: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3 $$

Find  $$L \left(\begin {bmatrix}
            u\\
            v\\
            w\\
           \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
I have no idea where to even start. Can someone please explain.

I figured out the first part of the problem which was to find $$L: \left(\begin {bmatrix}
2\\
-3\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) $$ which lead me to this answer: $$ \left(\begin {bmatrix}
-19\\
-7\\
-6\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ it is just the second part that I don't understand.

Comment: This looks incomplete.  Is anything missing?

Comment: Multiply the matrix $A$ with the vector (or column matrix)$(u,v,w)$. I think that's what has to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation. Let $M$ be the standard matrix of $T$. This means that for any $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $Mu = T(u)$.

In your case, you want to find
\begin{align*}
L\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
          -8 & 3 & 6\\
          -3 & 1 & 2 \\
          -3 & 1 & 3\\
          \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay, so I multiply matrix A for L and get the rref of it?

Comment: No, wait! I got it! Thank you! =)